# How can I remove the platforms I do not need to compile for in .net MAUI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui

I only want to make a project for MacOS and Windows, no need for Android or iOS. I tried deleting the platforms from the folder called "Platforms" but they seem to regenerate each compile. Is there an official method for only targeting the platforms that are necessary? I looked at multiple project files, but there are Android and iOS tags scattered throughout.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: delete the references in the `csproj` file

Answer (score 51, accepted):

###### Required Change

- In your `.csproj` file, remove the targets for the platforms you aren't building for, reducing it to the following:

  ```xml
  <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
  <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
  ```

###### Optional Changes

- In your `.csproj` file, remove the supported version information for the platforms you aren't building for, reducing it to the following:

  ```xml
  <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  ```
- Delete any subdirectories under the `Platforms` folder for the platforms you aren't building for.

###### Caveats

- You can only build for the Windows platform on a Windows machine.
- You can only build for MacCatalyst from a Mac, or from a Windows machine that has been set up with [Pair to Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac).

Comment: Thanks again, worked like a charm. And I'm compiling even faster.

Comment: Also keep in mind for C# files, while `#if IOS` and `#if MACCATALYST` are for their respective platforms, `#if __IOS__` covers *both*.

Comment: I did this and it worked without any issues. but now  I can't publish the application. "publish" is disabled when I right-click on the project.

Answer (score 7):

Remove platforms from `Debug Target`

Right click on Project and go on *Edit Project File*, Inside `PropertyGroup`, there will be below lines

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

**Remove Windows Project**

remove second line. Your code look like this

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<!--<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>-->
```

**Remove iOS and Mac Catalyst**

change first line to

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

**Remove Windows, iOS and Mac Catalyst**

remove second line, and make changes in first line. Your code look like this

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
<!--<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>-->
```

Once you remove project references from `.csproj`, even you can Delete projects (not required ones) from solution . In project go to Platforms folder and Delete project.